# How to stream RTMP live video in Android

Tags: android, rtmp

I have developed an application on Android for live streaming through [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) and it's working fine. I am able to play the RTSP [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) with the help of [Daroon Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.daroonplayer.dsplayer) and [Wondershare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wondershare.mobilego). The running code for RTSP is:

```
Uri stream = Uri.parse("rtsp://media-us-2.soundreach.net/slcn_lifestyle.sdp"); 
Intent videointent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,stream); 
startActivity(videointent);
```

Now I have to stream the live video through RTMP, but I am not able to invoke it with the above process. The requirement is to play the RTMP URL with the Wondershare only.

How would I play the RTMP URL on an Android device with the help of a third-party application, that is, wondershare?

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at [Vitamio](http://vitamio.org/). It is a nice library for playing multimedia content.

Comment: Any tutorial to play rmtp file with vitamino??

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code, but instead of Daroon Player, play it with [MX Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) Library for android. Only drawback is that it has a license.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/) for it.